# Integrate every single street into ArcGIS network analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

This is my first time working with a network analysis (ArcMap 10) and there are some problems which haven't been solved until now.

I have bus stops and Streets (with length, slope, time from-to for a pedestrian (2.5 km/h)).

I want to figure out from which point a person in a village can reach the bus stop within 5, 10 and 15 min. ( I did an ESRI tutorial about this topic, and actually it shouldn't be so difficult, but the tutorial data was well prepared)
At first I don't want to add slope restrictions. I just want to generate polygons around the bus stops with 5,10 and 15 min.

The result is quite weird. It seems that some streets have been analysed but others haven't been. (see screen)

All roads are connected and they have no further restrictions so i wonder why they are not displayed in analysis.

[image]

Comment: Are the streets one-way?

Comment: no they aren't! But see below, maybe its solved!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to planarize your streets layer to make sure that there is a node at every intersection of a road.

If not, Network Analyst will not recognize that a turn can be made from one road to another.

Make sure your roads are planarized and then rebuild your network dataset.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer!
It took me some time to planarize, but i think it helped!
What is more, I fixed an calculating-error concerning the pedestrian_time.

See the screenshot - I think the problem is solved! Maybe. I will analyse the result tomorrow in detail.
Thanks a lot!
Hannes

http://www.students.uni-marburg.de/~Blitza/busstop_solved_maybe.jpg